# Suspend from shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, command-line, suspend

I've tried to add a shorcut with the command:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

in Freya with no result.

When I run that command in terminal I get this:

```
"Error org.freedesktop.UPower.GeneralError: No kernel support"
```

Is there a special (different from ubuntu) command to suspend Elementary without sudo?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command working on freya is:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend" boolean:true
```

The `pmi action suspend` not working, so

To create keyboard shortcut key see [here](http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/10/17/howto-suspend-ubuntu-from-terminal-or-keyboard-shortcuts/).

Reference [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/542944/439451)

Comment: Works also in Loki (tested in beta2)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Ravan for the above answer, for suspend, if anybody is looking for Hibernate, the best way is to look out for Suspend key word in above answer and replace it carefully with Hibernate, and it looks like

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Hibernate" boolean:true
```

Though it will only run with `sudo`

Tried on Freya and it worked.